# JQuery Selector best practice

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When exposing a jquery script that will be used across multiple pages is it preferred to base the selector on an id or css class?

Comment: I don't think there is a best practice. I'd say whichever you prefer, but it may also matter (a little) whether the idea of what you are doing could apply to multiple elements on the same page or not.

Comment: Who cares as long as you don't mess up and start attaching unwanted events to elements with the same selector etc. Otherwise ID is usually preferrable as it's easier to look up in all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice would be to use both: ids whenever you need to select elements that are unique within a page and classes whenever you need to select multiple elements.

Answer (score 0):

Class selectors are designed to select more than one element, whereas if you use an ID selector it would be expected that only one element will match the selection. That point alone would drive me to think that an ID selector is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a good practice to keep ids unique on a page.  So if you select based on id, the script can only apply to 1 element on the page.

If you use classes, you can apply the script to multiple elements.

It all depends on what your script needs.

I would think about the *semantics* of your script.  Is it supposed to work on *specific* instances of things (id) or certain classes of things (css class)?